# Writing a HtmlHelper 'Table' method, which uses the model DisplayName's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have recently decided to write a generic Table html helper to generate tables for my models and other objects, I have used reflection to make it more generic by taking an IEnumerable argument as the table data and a Dictionary for the .

I want to use reflection or some other method to get the properties [DisplayName()] attribute from the models MetaData so that it does not need to be specified in a dictionary. However all methods I have tried seem to return null, so I have removed them from my code.

```
public static MvcHtmlString Table(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Dictionary<string, string> boundColumns, IEnumerable<object> objectData, string tagId, string className, string controllerName, string idProperty)
        {
            bool hasAction = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(idProperty);
            bool hasData = objectData.Count() > 0;
            UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

            Type objectDataType = hasData ? objectData.First().GetType() : null;
            IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> objectDataProperties = hasData ? from propInfo in objectDataType.GetProperties()
                                                                       where boundColumns.ContainsKey(propInfo.Name)
                                                                       select propInfo : null;

            // Thead
            TagBuilder theadtr = new TagBuilder("tr");
            foreach (string col in boundColumns.Values)
                theadtr.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}\n{1}", theadtr.InnerHtml, (new TagBuilder("th") { InnerHtml = col }).ToString());
            if (hasAction)
                theadtr.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}\n{1}", theadtr.InnerHtml, new TagBuilder("th") { InnerHtml = "Action" });
            TagBuilder thead = new TagBuilder("thead") { InnerHtml = theadtr.ToString() };

            // Tfoot
            TagBuilder tfoot = new TagBuilder("tfoot");
            if (!hasData) // Warn that there was no data to be displayed.
            {
                TagBuilder tfoottd = new TagBuilder("td") { InnerHtml = "There is currently nothing to display." };
                tfoottd.MergeAttribute("colspan", (hasAction ? (boundColumns.Count + 1) : boundColumns.Count).ToString());
                tfoottd.MergeAttribute("style", "text-align:center");
                tfoot.InnerHtml = (new TagBuilder("tr") { InnerHtml = tfoottd.ToString() }).ToString();
            }
            else // Display a pager & filter for navigating through large amounts of data.
            {
                // The button for navigating to the first page.
                TagBuilder pagefirst = new TagBuilder("img");
                pagefirst.MergeAttribute("id", String.Format("{0}-page-first", tagId));
                pagefirst.MergeAttribute("class", "first");
                pagefirst.MergeAttribute("alt", "First Page");
                pagefirst.MergeAttribute("src", urlHelper.Content("~/Content/Style/Tables/Themes/Blue/resultset_first.png"));
                pagefirst.MergeAttribute("style", "cursor:pointer; vertical-align:middle;");

                // The button for navigating to the previous page.
                TagBuilder pageprev = new TagBuilder("img");
                pageprev.MergeAttribute("id", String.Format("{0}-page-prev", tagId));
                pageprev.MergeAttribute("class", "prev");
                pageprev.MergeAttribute("alt", "Previous Page");
                pageprev.MergeAttribute("src", urlHelper.Content("~/Content/Style/Tables/Themes/Blue/resultset_previous.png"));
                pageprev.MergeAttribute("style", "cursor:pointer; vertical-align:middle;");

                // The button for navigating to the next page.
                TagBuilder pagenext = new TagBuilder("img");
                pagenext.MergeAttribute("id", String.Format("{0}-page-next", tagId));
                pagenext.MergeAttribute("class", "next");
                pagenext.MergeAttribute("alt", "Next Page");
                pagenext.MergeAttribute("src", urlHelper.Content("~/Content/Style/Tables/Themes/Blue/resultset_next.png"));
                pagenext.MergeAttribute("style", "cursor:pointer; vertical-align:middle;");

                // The button for navigating to the last page.
                TagBuilder pagelast = new TagBuilder("img");
                pagelast.MergeAttribute("id", String.Format("{0}-page-last", tagId));
                pagelast.MergeAttribute("class", "last");
                pagelast.MergeAttribute("alt", "Last Page");
                pagelast.MergeAttribute("src", urlHelper.Content("~/Content/Style/Tables/Themes/Blue/resultset_last.png"));
                pagelast.MergeAttribute("style", "cursor:pointer; vertical-align:middle;");

                // The display field for the pager status.
                TagBuilder pagedisplay = new TagBuilder("input");
                pagedisplay.MergeAttribute("id", String.Format("{0}-page-display", tagId));
                pagedisplay.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
                pagedisplay.MergeAttribute("class", "pagedisplay");
                pagedisplay.MergeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                pagedisplay.MergeAttribute("style", "width:12%;");

                // The select for changing page size.
                TagBuilder pagesize = new TagBuilder("select");
                pagesize.MergeAttribute("id", String.Format("{0}-page-size", tagId));
                pagesize.MergeAttribute("class", "pagesize");
                pagesize.MergeAttribute("style", "width:12%;");
                for (int i = 10; i <= 100; i += 10)
                {
                    TagBuilder option = new TagBuilder("option") { InnerHtml = i.ToString() };
                    if (i == 10)
                        option.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected");
                    option.MergeAttribute("value", i.ToString());

                    pagesize.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}\n{1}", pagesize.InnerHtml, option.ToString());
                }

                // The pager container.
                TagBuilder pagediv = new TagBuilder("div") { InnerHtml = (new TagBuilder("form") { InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}", pagefirst.ToString(), pageprev.ToString(), pagenext.ToString(), pagelast.ToString(), pagedisplay.ToString(), pagesize.ToString()) }).ToString() };
                pagediv.MergeAttribute("id", String.Format("{0}-pager", tagId));
                pagediv.MergeAttribute("style", "float:left; width:50%;");

                // Filter Text Field
                TagBuilder filterfield = new TagBuilder("input");
                filterfield.MergeAttribute("id", String.Format("{0}-filter-field", tagId));
                filterfield.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
                filterfield.MergeAttribute("style", "width:30%;");

                // The filter container.
                TagBuilder filterdiv = new TagBuilder("div") { InnerHtml = (new TagBuilder("form") {InnerHtml = String.Format("Search: {0}", filterfield.ToString())}).ToString() };
                filterdiv.MergeAttribute("id", String.Format("{0}-filter", tagId));
                filterdiv.MergeAttribute("style", "float:right; width:50%;");

                TagBuilder tfoottd = new TagBuilder("td") { InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}\n{1}", pagediv.ToString(), filterdiv.ToString()) };
                tfoottd.MergeAttribute("colspan", (hasAction ? (boundColumns.Count + 1) : boundColumns.Count).ToString());
                tfoottd.MergeAttribute("style", "text-align:center");
                tfoot.InnerHtml = (new TagBuilder("tr") { InnerHtml = tfoottd.ToString() }).ToString();
            }

            // Tbody
            TagBuilder tbody = new TagBuilder("tbody");
            foreach (object o in objectData)
            {
                TagBuilder tbodytr = new TagBuilder("tr");
                foreach (PropertyInfo p in objectDataProperties)
                {
                    string val = "N/A";
                    object pval = p.GetValue(o, null);
                    if (pval != null)
                        val = pval.ToString();
                    tbodytr.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}\n{1}", tbodytr.InnerHtml, (new TagBuilder("td") { InnerHtml = val }).ToString());
                }

                if (hasAction)
                {
                    string id = objectDataType.GetProperty(idProperty).GetValue(o, null).ToString();
                    tbodytr.InnerHtml = String.Format(
                        "{0}\n{1}",
                        tbodytr.InnerHtml,
                        (new TagBuilder("td") { InnerHtml = Table_ActionLinks(htmlHelper, controllerName, id) }).
                            ToString());
                }

                tbody.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}\n{1}", tbody.InnerHtml, tbodytr.ToString());
            }

            // Table
            TagBuilder table = new TagBuilder("table") { InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}", thead.ToString(), tfoot.ToString(), tbody.ToString()) };
            table.MergeAttribute("id", string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagId) ? String.Format("table-{0}", boundColumns.Count.ToString()) : tagId);
            table.MergeAttribute("summary", "Generic data list");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
                table.MergeAttribute("class", String.Format("{0} {1}", className, "tablesorter"));
            else
                table.MergeAttribute("class", "tablesorter");

            // Enable Sorting/Searching
            if (hasData)
            {
                TagBuilder sortscript = new TagBuilder("script") { InnerHtml = String.Format("$(document).ready(function(){{$(\"#{0}\").tablesorter().tablesorterPager({{container:$(\"#{1}\")}});}});", tagId, String.Format("{0}-pager", tagId)) };
                TagBuilder searchscript = new TagBuilder("script") { InnerHtml = String.Format("$(document).ready(function(){{$(\"#{0}\").keyup(function(){{$.uiTableFilter($(\"#{1}\"), this.value);}})}});", String.Format("{0}-filter-field", tagId), tagId) };
                sortscript.MergeAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                return new MvcHtmlString(String.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}", table.ToString(), sortscript.ToString(), searchscript.ToString()));
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString(table.ToString());
        }
```

So basically I am looking to use as much reflection as possible to eliminate as many arguments to this method as possible.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: this is not an answer, you could try usnig MVCContrib Grid http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LegacyGrid , http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your Display attribute retrieval isn't working. Here's what I use. It's from a method which retrieves the Display attribute from enum field values, but it's the same basic pattern that I use to retrieve any attribute from an object:

```
public static string GetDisplayName<T>( T toCheck )
{
  Type enumType = typeof(T);
  if( !enumType.IsEnum ) return null;

  MemberInfo[] members = enumType.GetMember(toCheck.ToString());

  if( ( members == null ) || ( members.Length != 1 ) ) return toCheck.ToString();

  foreach( MemberInfo memInfo in members )
  {
      DisplayAttribute[] attrs = (DisplayAttribute[]) memInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);

      if( ( attrs != null ) && ( attrs.Length == 1 ) ) return attrs[0].Name;
  }

  return toCheck.ToString();
}
```